# Java Regex to extract substring with optional trailing slash

Tags: java, regex

Regex:

```
\/test\/(.*|\/?)
```

Input

```
/something/test/{abc}/listed

/something/test/{abc}
```

Expected

`{abc}` for both the inputs

Comment: Are you looking to match or to extract?

Comment: i want to extract the substring.,. ie. {abc}

Comment: Maybe http://ideone.com/BLMapX?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer is BEST.. very simple and matches all the occurances.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Actually, you should ask your question more clearly, we can't exactly know you just want {abc} all the time or want the string in the brackets '{' and '}'
along with the brackets

Comment: Good, I posted with explanations.

Comment: @ChitKhine Didn't i say that {abc} for both the inputs , is that not meant that i always need including {} brackets?

Comment: @tales It is pretty clear that you need the brackets, but from your question , you makes it sound like you just want {abc} for any kind of string. for instance, xxxx-xxxx{abc}xxx, you just want {abc} but I don't think that is not what you want.

Comment: Yes. I want {abc}.. sorry i don't understand what you mean with "but I don't think that is not what you want"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture all characters other than `/` after `/test/`:

```
String s = "/something/test/{abc}/listed";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/test/([^/]+)"); // or "/test/\\{([^/}]+)"
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See [the online demo](http://ideone.com/BLMapX)

*Details*:

- `/test/` - matches `/test/`
- `([^/]+)` - matches and *captures* into Group 1 one or more (`+`) (but as many as possible, since `+` is greedy) characters other than `/` (due to the negated character class `[^/]`).

Note that in Java regex patterns you do not need to escape `/` since it is not a special character and one needs no regex delimiters.

Comment: Simple and BEST solution.. thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: One thing, now if i want to replace that result {abc} with something with replaceAll , then it replaces the /test also.. why is this?

Comment: No, if you need to *replace*, you should *capture* the part you need to keep, and just match what you need to replace. So, try `s.replaceFirst("(/test/)[^/]+", "$1")` (I assume there is only 1 value to replace, so, use `.replaceFirst` rather than `replaceAll`).

Comment: Thanks.. what i want to do is to mask that result.. so output looks like /something/test/*****/listed or /something/test/*****

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "/something/test/{abc}/listed";
    String s2 = "/something/test/{abc}";

    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("[^{]+(\\{\\w+\\}).*", "$1"));
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("[^{]+(\\{\\w+\\}).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
{abc}
{abc}
```

Comment: This works.. but can you also include the {} brackets in the result? so i get {abc} as ouput. thanks.

Comment: I need to get everything between /test/ AND optional /

Answer (score 0):

Regex (as Java string, that is with doubled backslashes):

```
".*\\/test\\/([^/]*).*"
```